# Exit Relay Warning: All nameservers have failed

Tags: exit-relays, windows

Shortly after starting my exit relay I start to get a spam of messages that look something like this:

```
Jun 20 17:09:48.269 [Warning] eventdns: All nameservers have failed
Jun 20 17:09:54.253 [Notice] eventdns: Nameserver 192.168.1.1:53 is back up
```

After hours of uptime, despite the program reporting itself to be "online", the relay does not appear as online in Tor Atlas or Tor Globe.

The server is behind a firewall/NAT but everything has been properly configured (appropriate port forwarding completed, firewall access allowed).

The relay runs upon a 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2 with Tor 0.2.4.22

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that Atlas is totally broken, and Globe is flaky.  I use http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/

The eventdns error messages appear to be a [known problem](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/2964) with Tor going back many years, if you just do a Google search.  One person claimed to have [fixed it](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-relays/2013-September/002783.html) by running a recursive DNS server locally.